# Find equilibrium points and eigen values of a system of differential equations

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, eigenvalue

I have a system of non-linear differential equations that model memory processes in the brain. I am using scipy.integrate.odeint to solve this system of ODEs. This is the first step and this executes fine. I get a good oscillating system.

The next step, however, is to find the equilibrium points and eigen values of this oscillating system which will prove what kind of bifurcation I am seeing. In python, this seems to be an impossible task. As far as I have googled, people speak about using AUTO in xppaut but I am not comfortable using any other tool as that involves lot of redundant work.

Is it possible to find the equilibrium points and eigen values of a system of ODEs in python?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Esash

Comment: The equilibrium points are the roots of the right side function. Use scipy.optimize.fsolve to find them, if you know good starting points. Explore other procedures contained in this sub-package. Somewhere there are also tools for numerical differentiation, so that you can use numpy.linalg.eig to find eigenvalues.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann Just a small comment, fsolve is now considered [Legacy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#legacy-functions) and [root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding) should be used instead.